# Sorting the alphabetic citations with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

EDIT:@PLK
**In fact, this happens only with texlive 2016 (up to date) with biblatex 3.4, and not with texlive 2015 up to date....
I forgot that I was on texlive 2016, not on the stable one.**

================

EDIT:@PLK, this is the MWE. I do get the first picture, after xelatex-biber-xelatex, which is what I want, but if I compile again with xelatex only, then I lose it and get the second picture.

```
\documentclass{article}




  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage{german}

%\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,   citetracker=true, citestyle=alphabetic, bibstyle=ieee-alphabetic, sorting=ynt,sortcites=true]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{testcite.bib} 


\usepackage{filecontents} \begin{filecontents}{testcite.bib}
@book{a01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{a02,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@article{c01,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@article{c02,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Charlie},
}

@article{c03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {1978},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@article{c04,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {1981},
  title = {Charlie},
}

@article{ac01,
  author = {Cuthor, C. and Author, A.},
  year = {1987},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@article{ac02,
  author = {Cuthor, C. and Author, A.},
  year = {1973},
  title = {Charlie},
}

@article{ac03,
  author = {Cuthor, C. and Author, A.},
  year = {1981},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}
Refs. \cite{a01, a02, ac01, ac02, c01, c02, c03, c04, ac03}

\today

%\clearpage


\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\selectlanguage{german}
\printbibliography[ heading=subbibliography,title={Journals}]
\endrefcontext
\end{document}
```

[image: this is what happens when I launch biber and xelatex the first time]

## [image: this what happens when I keep launching xelatex]

Edit:@PLK, you are right, but I print the bibliography with the sorting `nyt`, whereas I want the cites with, like you said, `ynt`...
this is the code that I use to print the bibliography (I use `xelatex`)

```
\clearpage


\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
%\selectlanguage{english}
\printbibliography
\endrefcontext
```

When I put this `newrefcontext`, the sorting of the cites changes, from `ynt` to `nyt`!

=============================================================

@murugan

check that you have the package  `filecontents` and the file `the title of your personal document.bib` in the folder where you compile...

==========================================

I use the following settings and my citations are not ordered

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=alphabetic,bibstyle=ieee-alphabetic, backend=biber,sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{} % Remove annoying dash
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents} \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{a02,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@article{c01,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@article{c02,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Charlie},
}

@article{c03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {1978},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@article{c04,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {1981},
  title = {Charlie},
}

@article{ac01,
  author = {Cuthor, C. and Author, A.},
  year = {1987},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@article{ac02,
  author = {Cuthor, C. and Author, A.},
  year = {1973},
  title = {Charlie},
}

@article{ac03,
  author = {Cuthor, C. and Author, A.},
  year = {1981},
  title = {Charlie},
}


\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}
Refs. \cite{a01, a02, ac01, ac02, c01, c02, c03, c04, ac03}\\
\end{document}
```

This is the order that I seek

- first sorting is by year
- for two items of the same year, order by name of the first author
- if the items have same year and same first author, put first the items **which have only 1 author**, then the items with co-authors
  **[these items with co-authors will be sorted first by year, then alphabetically by the name of the first co-author]**

I think I have stated all the cases. Explicitly, I get currently,

> [Aut01; Aut02; CA73; CA81; CA87; Cut03; Cut04; Cut78; Cut81]

I want

> [CA73; Cut78;  Cut81; CA81; CA87; Aut01; Aut02; Cut03; Cut04]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the biblatex option `sorting=ynt` to your biblatex options since `sortcites` uses the global sorting scheme. This gives you the order you want. If you want different sorting for the actual bibliography list, you can put your `\printbibliography` inside a `\refsection` with a different sorting scheme.

Comment: I do not get actual bibliography list. Why? please give full code

Comment: Just add `\printbibliography` before the `\end{document}`

Comment: Not coming. I do not know the reason.

Comment: Can you edit your MWE to be an exact copy of what you are doing and tell us exactly which commands you are running?

Comment: @PLK In fact, this happens only with texlive 2016 (up to date) with biblatex 3.4, and not with texlive 2015 up to date....
I forgot that I was on texlive 2016, not on the stable one.

Comment: the bug also happens with lualatex in texlive 2016.

Comment: Hmm, do you have the latest biblatex 3.4 and biber 2.5 from sourceforge? I am using these and it's fine for me.

Comment: I just updated to 2016 pretest and am using the latest biblatex 3.4 and biber 2.5 and your MWE with an added `\printbibliography` works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks. I am with MikTex 2.9 (64 bit windows).So it is not working.

Comment: This was indeed a bug in the latest dev biblatex 3.4. Please get the latest DEV 3.4 from Sourceforge and try it. You don't need to update biber too.